# WSO2 enterprise integrator - datasource

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

do you know where is save settings about datasource from wso2 EI? 
i create datasource on GUI in wso2 but I can't find record on server.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find the dataservice file under,

> EI-Home/repository/deployment/server/dataservices

Datasources added from Management Console will be stored in registry,

> /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource/

Comment: this is dataservices not datasource from gui

Answer (score 1):

The data sources added from the Management console UI is saved to the registry under /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource registry path. You can navigate to the registry path from management console UI and you can download the data source definition created from there. 
[registry path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvYQC.png)

If you need to add data source definitions from the file system you can create a file with format {any_name}-datasources.xml and put the data source configurations and save it under {SERVER_HOME}/conf/datasources